# Union of adjacent shapes in C#/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, geometry

I'm using a `CombinedGeometry` in C# to join several polygons together.

The `RenderedGeometry` of each shape is taken, and joined to the final shape with `GeometryCombineMode.Union`.

However, I'm having a problem where two shapes are adjacent, but not overlapping (a 0px gap between the two). As they do not overlap, they will not be joined by the `CombinedGeometry`.

I've considered enlarging each input shape by 1 pixel, then contracting the output by the same, but this can't be done accurately using a `ScaleTransform`.

How can I join these two shapes together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following - I've not tested it, but logically I think it will work:

Create a rectangle that encloses your shapes - calculate the combined bounding box and extend it a bit to cope with rounding error.

Then perform a "Exclude" between the rectangle and each shape in turn.

Once you've done that you'll have a rectangle with a hole cut out that's the effective union of all your shapes.

Then do an "Xor" of the this with another rectangle the same size as the first.

I think this should produce your "union".

Comment: I didn't implement this, but I can't see any reason why it wouldn't have worked either, so I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: @dig412 - what did you go with in the end?

Comment: I found that RenderedGeometry was 0.5 - 1px inaccurate, which meant my previously overlapping shapes had a slight gap between them. I just constructed a new Geometry for them with the width and height of the original shape.